# Transform log posterior probabilities for Bayesian model averaging

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, normalization, model, posterior

I have four models, each one is run with MCMC on a large number phylogenetic trees. Each resulting model has an associated log posterior probability (sum of the log likelihood and log prior). Since I need to average the models weighting by their posteriors (bayesian model averaging) I need the original posterior probabilities. How can I standardize them from 0 to 1? Should I normalize among the four model for each tree?
Also consider that my log posteriors are negative and very low (<-700), then when I calculate their exponential I get 0.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since your posteriors have an unknown scale (the normalizing constant), you can shift their logs (all by the same amount) without changing the relative probabilities. Just add, say 700, or, say whatever it takes to make the biggest of them 0, or whatever you find convenient.